# Do I need to autorelease out parameters of my function ?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that accepts three NSMutableArrays, one as Input and two as output using pointer to a  pointer.

Now I am creating the two arrays inside the method.

So the memory allocation is done inside the method therefore it should be method's responsibility to release the memory.

So should I call autorelease on the objects before assigning them to these output references ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `autorelease` them. But make sure that, after the method call, you call `retain` on both the output pointers. Release them once you are done with them

```
NSMutableArrays *arr1, arr2, arr3;
[self methodOne:arr1 two:*arr2 three:*arr3];
[arr2 retain];
[arr3 retain];
```

Comment: Why? You only need to retain `arr2` and `arr3` in your example if you're going to hold onto those references. If you don't plan to use them outside the current method (more properly, beyond the scope of the current autorelease pool), there's no need to retain them.

Comment: Ofcourse will have two only retain arr2 and arr3 as they r being autoreleased and created inside the method.
the first one is already created and passed to this method which helps  it to generate the other two.

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate or retain an object, you need to release or autorelease it. It's as simple as that.